# Oracle PL/SQL Procedure to split comma separated data in source table and push in destination table

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, procedure

I have used regexp to split comma separated code into columns and insert same into destination table.
I need to put this inside pl/sql procedure.
It should empty the destination table first and then populate everytime it is run.
It should be a loop and insert row by row.

DB is Oracle 12c.

```
Delete from dest_data;
insert into dest_data(seq_id,rad_id,column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6,column_7)
with rcte (id, sep_String, lvl, result) as (
  select rad_id, string, 1, regexp_substr(string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from source_data
  union all
  select id, sep_String, lvl + 1, regexp_substr(sep_String, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where lvl <= regexp_count(data, ',')
)
select *
from (
  select rad_seq.nextval,id, lvl, result --here i wish to use sequence but am not able to--
  from rcte
)
pivot (max(result) as col for (lvl) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
```

Sequence is used as the first column is pk and needs to be a unique number assignEd to all rows .

Comment: You have done everything already ? What is not working  ? Did you try with any sort of pl/SQL ?

Comment: i need to put this in pl/sql procedure. This insert was for one row. I need to do this for all rows like looping. which would increment the rad_seq.nextval column the sequence here is not working. SO i wish to write procedure and add loop where it would increment with 1 for each row.

Comment: so create procedure, then it would emplty the dest_data table, then in loop start inserting the rows from source table with the first column seq_id incrementing with 1.

Comment: the splitting is fine. i need to wrap this in procedure with loop and that is what i am unable to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the data for insertion is in place and only problems with the column you need an auto increment,

In Oracle 12c we have two options to achieve it while creating the table itself,

**Option 1:** **using Identity Columns**.

More option with `IDENTITY` options can be explored [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1).

```
CREATE TABLE dest_data (
  seq_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  .....
  .....
);
```

**Option 2:** DEFAULT Values Using Sequences

More in formations with default column value [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1)

```
CREATE TABLE dest_data (
  seq_id NUMBER DEFAULT rad_seq.nextval,
  .....
  .....
);
```

Once you created the tables with any option above , exclude the insertion of `seq_id` from the insert statement and it will be handled by oracle.

***Edit:-***

Forgot to add the point , if it's one time activity you don't need a dedicated procedure and can be achieved via an anonymous block enclosed within `BEGIN` `END` and if you need a procedure anyway just create one with no parameter and within procedure body just copy the two statement and a commit without any loop to generate sequence. Hope to is clear or else please try and give feedback.